# What is the factory default size of the dock in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, dock, osx-el-capitan

On a fresh install this shows nothing:

```
defaults read com.apple.dock tilesize
```

I'm trying to set it back to it was when I installed El Capitan. I accidentally grabbed the slider and resized it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out it is 64 - found this out by deleting the value, restarting the dock, clicking on the resizing area but not dragging it, letting go, and then checking the value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your research! I was able to reset my dock to the default size with `defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize 64`.